# why can't xcodebuild find gcc 4-2 after installing XCode 4.2?

Tags: iphone, xcode, gcc, makefile, xcode4.2

I am trying to compile something from the Terminal command line. When I run make it gives me this error:

```
error: can't exec '/Developer/Library/Xcode/PrivatePlugIns/Xcode3Core.ideplugin/Contents/Frameworks/DevToolsCore.framework/Resources/gcc-4.2' (No such file or directory)
```

How do I resolve this? Why isn't gcc-4.2 found there? Actually my gcc is located at /usr/bin.
Can someone help me to sort this out?

**UPDATE:**

Here's my Makefile

```
default:
    xcodebuild -target "Tests (Device)" -configuration Release
    xcodebuild -target "Tests (Simulator)" -configuration Release
    BUILD_DIR="build" BUILD_STYLE="Release" sh ../Scripts/CombineLibs.sh
    sh ../Scripts/iOSFramework.sh

# If you need to clean a specific target/configuration: $(COMMAND) -target $(TARGET) -configuration DebugOrRelease -sdk $(SDK) clean
clean:
    -rm -rf build/*

test:
    GHUNIT_CLI=1 xcodebuild -target Tests -configuration Debug -sdk iphonesimulator build
```

Comment: how are you doing the compiling on the command line?  are you using a `make` file or `xcodebuild` or?

Comment: it's using the xcodebuild, I updated with my Makefile above

Comment: What happens if you run "gcc-4.2" on its own with no parameters?

Comment: @jrtc27if you mean just typing that on the terminal then it says command not found

Answer (score -2):

Since XCode 4.2, Apple changed the C compiler from "GCC 4.2" to "Apple LLVM compiler 3.0"

Comment: Not what the OP was asking. GCC is still there.